# Cleaning VBA needed for Search and Replace

Tags: excel, vba, find-replace

I am new in VBA so i just look for the code online and i modify it for my files.

I would like to know if i can put together the following 2 macros.
It looks for contract number in column AF and then changes the Customer Name (col AN) & Customer Group Name (col AP). can it be donein another way?

I would like to simplify it as later i need, based on Contract Number to change 5 more variables in 5 different columns for other customers.

```
Sub CorrectCustomerNameXXXX()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Range("AF1000000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("AF" & i) = "006-0146157-001" Then
        Range("AN" & i).Value = "CUSTOMER_NAME"
    End If
Next
End Sub



Sub CorrectCustomerGROUPNameXXXX()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

LastRow = Range("AF1000000").End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("AF" & i) = "006-0146157-001" Then
        Range("AP" & i).Value = "CUSTOMER_GROUP"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Should "006-0146157-001" be found more then once?

Comment: no the contract number is unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. You should use the same iteration:

```
Sub CorrectWhatever()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

LastRow = Range("AF" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Range("AF" & i).Value = "006-0146157-001" Then
        Range("AN" & i).Value = "CUSTOMER_NAME"
        Range("AP" & i).Value = "CUSTOMER_GROUP"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```